# How to use the JSON data via PHP from Google Insight API

Tags: php, json, google-api

I would like to use the data from Google Insight API via a PHP page. (Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v1/getting_started?hl=fr#example_commandline))

For example, how could I use the "numberJsResources" returned by Google Insight ?

```
$jsonString = curl "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/&key=MyAPIKey";

$obj = json_decode($jsonString);

echo $obj->responseCode;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using curl wrongly.

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/&key=MyAPIKey");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($res, true);
echo $obj['pageStats']['numberJsResources'];
```

Manual : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: I got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"https://www.googleapis.com/pa' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) on the line that corresponds to the one where I use curl

Comment: Ok then a complete code would be?:
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/&key=APIKEYHERE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $res;

    $obj = json_decode($res, true);
    $pageStats = $obj['pageStats'];
    echo $pageStats['numberJsResources'];

Comment: It is hard to read it from the comment but I think it is and also I had edited again before your comment:)

Comment: Yes I tried it. I doesn't get anything printed on screen. I try to see why.

Comment: try to print obj array. `print_r($obj);`

Comment: var_dump($obj); gives me NULL . I continue searching

Comment: I do realize that it wasn't working on local server (127.0.0.1) but do on web server. Thank you for your help!